# How to assess the effect of optimisation on software performance improvement based on five trials with and without optimisation?

Tags: confidence-interval, optimization, model-evaluation

[This question is similar to [How to assess the improvement from a treatment?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49944/how-to-assess-the-improvement-from-a-treatment)]

I'm attempting to characterize what appears to be an obvious improvement in performance as a result of some changes to a software application. I've run the application five times without the optimization ('A' represents the timing for such) and five times with the optimization ('B').

A = [12.6, 12.6, 12.5, 12.7, 12.7]

B = [4.3, 3.3, 4.3, 3.2, 3.3]

As a layman, this appears to represent a reasonable improvement in performance. However, I don't know how to *characterize* the legitimacy of that improvement.

Is my sample size large enough to allow me to claim anything from a statistical point of view?

Can I calculate a confidence with any statement of performance improvement or the measurements themselves?

Comment: Is there any reason that a test of difference in the observed means is not a suitable answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Independent groups t-test

The standard approach to data like this is to perform an independent groups t-test.

You can test this in R using the following simple command.

```
t.test(c(12.6, 12.6, 12.5, 12.7, 12.7), c(4.3, 3.3, 4.3, 3.2, 3.3))
```

The results are:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  c(12.6, 12.6, 12.5, 12.7, 12.7) and c(4.3, 3.3, 4.3, 3.2, 3.3)
t = 34.8517, df = 4.174, p-value = 2.638e-06
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 8.239347 9.640653
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    12.62      3.68
```

P is much less than .05, the 95% confidence intervals of the difference is much greater than zero, so all else being equal you would probably conclude that there is a real difference.

#### Broader considerations

I imagine that software optimisation involves a wide range of other issues that you would have to consider beyond standard statistical significance. I'd be asking question like

- Were the tests in the two conditions run under otherwise identical conditions?
- Were the tests run under a sufficiently broad range of conditions that the observed changes would generalise to the conditions where the software is typically run?

Comment: I appreciate your inclusion of the 'broader considerations'; these were in play when doing the experiment design. With respect to your suggestion of the independent groups t-test; thank you. That appears to be the sort of things that I was looking for. I still need to wrap my head around what some of those calculated values mean (I have other data sets which don't provide such a clean conclusion; e.g. what if the t value is negative? what if the p-value is much higher, etc.).

Comment: p<.05 is a common decision making threshold; t is positive if the first group mean is larger than the second group mean; t is negative if the first group mean is smaller than the second group mean.

Comment: +1 ... with a small caveat: "performance" frequently (though far from always) relates to things like completion times, which in some cases might be severely skewed. In some situations - especially if sample sizes are not small - this might lead us to consider something other than a straight t-test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to some NIST pages:

- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/ppc.htm
- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section5/ppc52.htm
- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/prc.htm

Here is the one that I think is most interesting to you:

- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc2.htm

Bottom lines:

- Mileage is going to vary based on system, measurements and changes.
- A good starting point is to look at the change in mean and change in standard deviation.  Make sure that you get enough samples to make an adequate comparison.