# Forming an unbiased estimator of the maximum of several parameters, given independent estimators of each parameter?

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, estimators

Say I have $K$ independent normals, $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ for $i = 1,...,K$. How can I form an unbiased estimator of $\max_i \mu_i$ using $X_i$'s?

Comment: This is impossible if you make no further assumptions and allow all $2K$ parameters to be unknown. To see why, consider situations where all the $\mu_i$ are distinct and the $\sigma_i$ are incredibly tiny. The *only* function of the data that could be unbiased for the maximum in this situation then obviously is the maximum of the data. However, that clearly is biased (high) in general for $K\ge 2$.  Would you like, therefore, to add assumptions about the parameters?

Comment: The question doesn't specify if multiple realizations are available for each $X_i,$ although it might imply it. If they are, then one could use the highest sample mean, no?

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for your help. Yes, using maximum of sample means will always bias upward. But I'm not getting why i can't form an unbiased estimate? And taking a step back, 1) what assumptions can I make on parameters to get an unbiased estimator, and 2) with no more assumptions, can I form at least an asymptotically consistent estimator?

Comment: What would the asymptotics be?  Evidently as $K$ grows so do the number of parameters *but how do they change with $K$*??

Answer (score 3):

In the simple case where all $\sigma$'s are known, this is impossible.

E.g for $k=2$, $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=1$:

> So long as $E[f(X,Y)]$ is always defined, there is no $f(x,y)$ such
> that $E[f(X,Y)]=\max(\mu_1,\mu_2)$.

If the identity held, it would mean:
$$\max(\mu,0)=\iint \frac{f(x,y)}{2\pi}e^{-((x-\mu)^2-y^2)/2}dx\,dy$$

Then differentiating with respect to $\mu$ would give:
$$\frac{d\max(\mu,0)}{d\mu}=\iint \frac{f(x,y)}{2\pi}e^{-((x-\mu)^2-y^2)/2}(\mu-x)dx\,dy$$

The right-hand side is a continuous function of $\mu$. But the left-hand side is $+1$ when $\mu$ is positive, is $0$ when $\mu$ is negative, and is undefined when $\mu$ is zero. So the left-hand side is discontinuous, and neither of the posited identities holds.

Comment: You implicitly assume $f$ is continuous!

Comment: I do not! $f$ is independent of $\mu$, and it is integrated against a function of $\mu$ with plenty of continuity.

Comment: I believe you: your condition on the expectation being defined does the job.  A big +1 for such a succinct, clever result!

Comment: I now see that this argument was already given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21916/225256